# How to highlight a row of information if a specific cell is less than the cell above it?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting

I am working in google spreadsheet, and I want to highlight an entire row of data at a time if the cell above is grater than that current row's cell:

My data is in column A:I and I would like to highlight across all these columns (if not just these columns then the entire row) for the following evaluation:

H25

I want this evaluation to go all the way down though the entire sheet so that H2

Example

```
     A     B     C
1 Jen    Tool    1
2 Ben    Tip     2
3 Jac    Tool    3
4 Ann    Wep     1
5 Cat    Wep     15
6 Bat    Tool    16
7 kdi    Tip     20
8 ndi    Tip     5
9 diu    Wep     4
```

Where rows 4, 8, and 9 would be highlighted because of the number in column c being less than the number above it.

Is this possible and how would it be done? What would be the apply to range? What would be the format rules? I'm guessing it's going to have to be a custom right?

Comment: Use conditional format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this formula on range **A2:Z**:

```
=($C2<$C1)*($C2<>"")
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you very much, and while it works perfectly I understand the answer less that I hoped I would, which leads me to the question what if I wanted to do it backwards, check that the the cell above was less than, and if true, then highlight?

Comment: it would be `=($C2>$C1)*($C2<>"")` applied to **A1:Z** range